# Unloading unused textures in Unity

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, optimization

I have swapped some of my *Sprite* objects in favour of *Meshes* **without textures** as they should take up less memory.

However, when checking my *Profiler*, even after the swap the used texture memory is all the same.

So I decided to *unload* those textures forcefully but things aren't going very well. 
My intention with this code is to find all the textures by the name of the *GameObject* they were on (as I just dragged the sprites on the scene via inspector, their name matches. I know which GO-s to look for as only they contain a *MeshFilter*) and then unload them by hand.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class DumpUnused : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TextureContainer swappedTextures = new TextureContainer();
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        RemoveSwappedTextures();
        var unloader = Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
        while (!unloader.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    private void RemoveSwappedTextures()
    {
        //getting all my scene objects that has a mesh filter.
        /*
         * NOTE: I swapped my sprites for generated meshes. 
         * However, the texture memory used didn't decrease so I bet they are still loaded.
         * The textures I used as sprites had the same name as the assets themselves as assets were 
         * just dragged on the scene.
         */
        var sceneObjects =
           UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>()
            .Where(g => g.GetComponent<MeshFilter>() != null);
        //we have the repaced gameobjects.

        //now to get the used textures by their names:
        foreach (var item in sceneObjects)
        {
            //getting everything, even assets
            var strToFind = GetOriginalName(item.name);
             swappedTextures.Append(
             Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Texture2D>()
             .Where(t => t.name.Equals(strToFind)
             ));
        }
        foreach (var text2Unload in swappedTextures)
        {
            //destroy the loaded textures.
            DestroyImmediate(text2Unload);
        }
        swappedTextures = null;
    }

    private string GetOriginalName(string name)
    {
        /*
         * getting the original asset name by the "unity populated name".
         * reason: say I have a "backGr" named texture. 
         * if I copy paste it all over the place, unity makes their name
         * "backGr (1)", "backGr (2)" and so on.
         * So I search until the first whitespace and anything before that
         * is the original name of the texture.
         */

        string str = "";
        char c;int i = 0;
        for (c = name[i]; i < name.Length && c != ' '; i++)
        {
            str += c;
        }
        return str;
    }

    public class TextureContainer : List<Texture2D>
    {
        //made only for convenience
        public void Append(IEnumerable<Texture2D> textures)
        {
            foreach (var _t in textures)
            {
                this.Add(_t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I guess it doesn't do what I want is because the used texture memory is all the same and used total memory is **even higher** than it was before.

So, unless it is normal for Unity to use more texture memory when there's less textures in the scene, I guess I messed up somewhere.

The question is, how to make this work? If I'm on the wrong road, what are the best practices to *Unload textures by name*?